# Force linear layout of nodes in graphviz?

Tags: git, graphviz

I am using graphviz to generate some git graph visualizations. For one example, I have a linear history that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to display the same history, but showing annotations for remote heads. If I just add the relationships to the graph, I get:

[image]

How would I convince `dot` to layout the commit nodes (`A` - `G`) in a straight line (as in the first example) in the example with remote heads?

The source for the second example looks something like this:

```
digraph {
    rankdir=RL

    {
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    G
    }

    G->F->E->D->C->B->A

    {
    node [shape=box, style=filled, color=black, fontcolor=white]
    master
    }

    master->G

    {
    node [shape=box, style=filled, color=grey, fontcolor=white]
    "origin/HEAD"
    "origin/master"
    "origin/topic1"
    "origin/topic2"
    }

    "origin/HEAD" -> B
    "origin/master" -> B
    "origin/topic1" -> D
    "origin/topic2" -> F
}
```

**Update 1**

It looks like setting `weight=0` on the edges, like this:

```
"origin/HEAD" -> B [weight=0]
"origin/master" -> B [weight=0]
"origin/topic1" -> D [weight=0]
"origin/topic2" -> F [weight=0]
```

Gets me closer:

[image]

That gets me the linear layout of the commit nodes; now I need to figure out how to reduce the length of those edges connecting the remote heads to the respective commits (and ideally keep the spacing between the commit nodes equal).

**Update 2**

Continuing to throw things against the wall, if I also set `constraint=false` for those edges, they no longer impact the spacing of the commit nodes:

```
"origin/HEAD" -> B [weight=0, constraint=false]
"origin/master" -> B [weight=0, constraint=false]
"origin/topic1" -> D [weight=0, constraint=false]
"origin/topic2" -> F [weight=0, constraint=false]
```

[image]

I get a lot closer if instead of modifying the edges I set `rankdir=TB` and `rank=same` for the commit nodes:

[image]

The problem here is that now the left-to-right positioning of the nodes is incorrect (and we once again have variant spacing between the nodes).

Answer (score 0):

By George, I think I've got it.

The answer is to set the [`group`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:group) attribute on the commit nodes, like this:

```
digraph {
    rankdir=RL
    edge [weight=2]

    {
    node [group=commits]
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    G
    }

    G->F->E->D->C->B->A

    {
    node [shape=box, style=filled, color=black, fontcolor=white]
    master
    }

    master->G

    {
    node [shape=box, style=filled, color=grey, fontcolor=white]
    "origin/HEAD"
    "origin/master"
    "origin/topic1"
    "origin/topic2"
    }

    "origin/HEAD" -> B
    "origin/master" -> B
    "origin/topic1" -> D
    "origin/topic2" -> F
}
```

Which results in:

[image]